# Use inferred type when creating a new literal type

Tags: typescript

I'd like to type an object that represents a store's catalog and then create a new literal type of all of the product names within the catalog.

This is the type for a store catalog:

```js
interface StoreCatalog {
  products: { name: string }[];
}
```

This is a store catalog:

```js
const groceryStoreConfig: StoreCatalog = {
  products: [{ name: "apples" }, { name: "bananas" }],
} as const;
```

When I create a type for the product names, I expect it to be `"apples" | "bananas"`, but instead get `string`.

```js
// type GroceryStoreProductNames = string
export type GroceryStoreProductNames =
  (typeof groceryStoreConfig)["products"][number]["name"];
```

If I remove the type from groceryStoreConfig I will get `"apples" | "bananas"`, but then I am free to add anything to the groceryStoreConfig even if it doesn't comply with the StoreCatalog type.

```js
// no type, so additional property is added without an error
const groceryStoreConfig = {
  products: [
    { name: "apples" },
    { name: "bananas", additionalProperty: "additional property" },
  ],
} as const;

// type GroceryStoreProductNames = "apples" | "bananas"
export type GroceryStoreProductNames =
  (typeof groceryStoreConfig)["products"][number]["name"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) operator. `satisfies` can be used in combination with the [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to guarantee type safety and prevent widening of types to their primitives (in your case to `string`).

First of all, you'll need to update the `StoreCatalog.products` to be a read-only array, since const assertion will make the arrays read-only:

```
interface StoreCatalog {
  products: readonly { name: string }[];
}
```

Testing:

```
const groceryStoreConfig = { 
  products: [{ name: 'apples' }, { name: 'bananas' }],
} as const satisfies StoreCatalog;

const groceryStoreConfig2 = {
  products: [{ name: 'apples' }, { name: 'bananas', additionalProperty: 'error' }], // error
} as const satisfies StoreCatalog;

// type GroceryStoreProductNames = "apples" | "bananas"
export type GroceryStoreProductNames =
  typeof groceryStoreConfig['products'][number]['name'];
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgPZQgYTmOAGwwHNkBvAKGWQAcoMATAVwTAGcAuZbORjEIQCeFZCDgBbCN3ZgooMgF8A2gF0A3JUWVKCAbOQkGSKEPRZcAmMDIBeCtToMWbLsmXkxk6cgDkcWlpCCHZfZEUAGlFxKW5fACM4cXFQ8NUIrWQ4dmQ9EAN2fGB2axC0TGw8AmISTV19MENjaDMKyxBrEgAmZHsqGnomVg5uDy9YvwCgkLDI6O84xOTs3yi+RmAwYAEiAAUGWmgwITjZ9OQAegvkaAYoTOzchuRCrZLgMvNK-CJSOqvkMdDsgAOLNUxfCD7IZsABy3hy9gARFNguwkcgAD7IJFLJLZJGUCAAD1oWEaQJQYIwJlaFmhLjA8KkiMclIwMCaNJakJwVhsyl8g0ZoVUyhAzAk8WgYt8MQgvg0lCAA)